# "Идеальный код" или "Совершенный код"

Tags: книги

Привет всем! На каникулы решил закупить книги по программированию. В процессе поиска "Совершенного кода" нашёл книгу "Идеальный код" Энди Орама (редактор серии O'Reilly) и Грегори Уилсона. 
Как вам эта книга по сравнению с "Совершенным кодом" ?

Comment: Прочитал книгу Совершенный код. Честно я мало с неё запомнил, может со мной что-то не так. но он немного трахается словами там. Я бы Энди Орама почитал

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Даже судя по оглавлению, "Идеальный код" -- простой сборник статей(примеров) из журналов. Сам недавно дочитал "Совершенный код", очень рекомендую сначала прочитать его.

Comment: еще неплохая книга "Чистый Код" Роберта Мартина

Comment: Спасибо. Сегодня начал её читать :)

Answer (score 10):

Я читал и "Совершенный код" и "Чистый код". Обе книги ОЧЕНЬ хороши, после них начинаешь писать понятнее и проще. Рекомендую.
"Идельный код" больше похож на "Programming Pearls"("Жечужины программирования"). Показаны примеры, как люди решали свои задачи и какие идеи им в голову приходили